# Probelm in retreiving backend to run a repeat until success circuit on qiskit

Tags: qiskit

I'm trying to run a repeat until success circuit on hardware by following instructions from qiskit tutorials. Here is the code:

```
from qiskit_ibm_provider import IBMProvider, least_busy

provider = IBMProvider()

hub = "\<hub\>"
group = "\<group\>"
project = "\<project\>"
hgp = f"{hub}/{group}/{project}"
backend_name = "\<backend name\>"

backend = provider.get_backend(backend_name, instance=hgp)
print(f"Using {backend.name}")
```

The error it shows is :
QiskitBackendNotFoundError:
'No backend matches the criteria'
The line **backend = provider.get_backend(backend_name, instance=hgp)** is showing this error.

I also tried replacing "<backend name>" qith the name of a backend , but still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way that a backend should be used for most people:

```
provider = IBMQ.get_provider(hub='HUB NAME', group='open', project='main')
device = provider.get_backend('QC NAME')
```

The hub name and the QC name could be found at:
https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/services/resources

for each respective quantum processor.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The solution worked.